# Не возможно создание Web application и проблемы c IIS

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь создать web application в visual studio 2015. Выдаёт сообщение об ошибке:

> configuring iis express failed with the following error: Initializing
>   the application.config file failed. Cannot find IIS Express.

Проект в директории создаётся, но пустой. Попытался создать виртуальный каталог, настроить webconfig проекта к url, который прописал в IIS, но ничего не вышло.

Подскажите возможные пути решения данной проблемы

Answer (score 1):

Решил данную проблему. Попробовал переустановить IIS express, который позволяет создавать локальные серверы для разработчиков